# Android and JNI, pipe data to FFmpeg

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I'm trying to create a metadata retriever based on FFmpeg. Since raw Android application resources are often only accessible using a file descriptor I need a way to pipe this data to FFmpeg via JNI. I know FFmpeg supports a "pipe" protocol:

```
UNIX pipe access protocol.

Allow to read and write from UNIX pipes.

The accepted syntax is: 

    pipe:[number]

number is the number corresponding to the file descriptor of the pipe (e.g. 0 for stdin, 1 for stdout, 2 for stderr). If number is not specified, by default the stdout file descriptor will be used for writing, stdin for reading.

For example: cat test.wav | ffmpeg -i pipe:0
```

My question is, how do I programmatically emulate `cat test.wav | ffmpeg -i pipe:0` using JNI and [avformat_open_input](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga10a404346c646e4ab58f4ed798baca32) using a [FileDescriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html)? Is this possible?

Comment: How about this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, can you rephrase the question?

Comment: I wanna ask how to create a named pipe in Java Layer, and pass on JNI

Answer (score 1):

People from [AndroidFFmpeg](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg) project implemented "jni://" protocol to stream data via JNI, see https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg/blob/master/FFmpegLibrary/jni/jni-protocol.c

I do not know how it's used, just I came across that file and saw your question. I think you could use the same solution.

You may want to look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24747137/1028256 about passing `FileDescriptor` to JNI

Comment: `You may want to look at this post...` You referred him to his own post.